# Threaded implementation of observer pattern - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, observer-pattern

I'm developing a C++ program which has a "scan" method which will trigger a relatively long running scanning procedure. When the procedure is completed, the scan method will notify observers of results using the observer pattern.

I would like to create a separate thread for each scan. This way I can run multiple scans simultaneously. When each scanning process completes, I would like the scan method to notify the listeners.

According the boost thread library, it looks like I can maybe do something like this:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::mutex io_mutex;

void scan(int scan_target, vector<Listener> listeners)  
{
  //...run scan 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock  
      lock(io_mutex);
    std::cout << "finished scan" << endl;
    // notify listeners by iterating through the vector
    // and calling "notify()

  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  vector<Listener> listeners
  // create 
  boost::thread thrd1(
    boost::bind(&scan, 1, listeners));
  boost::thread thrd2(
    boost::bind(&scan, 2, listeners));
  //thrd1.join();
  //thrd2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Does this look roughly correct? Do I need to mutex the call to listenrs? Is it ok to get rid of the joins?

Comment: What are you trying to protect with the mutex? The listener list? Are you trying to prevent overlapping iterations through the list?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need a lock or not depends on what you do with the notification. I think it would be more apt if you put the lock in notify function of only those listeners where you need a single threaded access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the boost stuff, but conceptually it looks right.  You have Observers that want to be notified of state changes.  When a "qualifying event" happens, you have to run through a list (or vector, something like that) of Observers to notify.  You also want to make sure somehow that concurrent notifications don't cause you trouble,

(Here's the [Wikipedia articl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)e on the pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Listener::Notify() is being called from multiple threads, so unless Notify() has no side effects, you'll have to do one of the three:

1. External lock (your example): acquiring a mutex before calling Listener::Notify()
2. Internal lock: Listener::Notify() will acquire a lock internally
3. Lock free: search for "lock free algorithm" in google

There are pros/cons for each option...

For what (i think) you need, option 1 will be good.

And, you'll have to keep the join statements otherwise your main() may exit before your threads can finish their job. Also consider using `boost::thread_pool` and `joint_all`.